# Event not firing for dropdown in Chrome Extension using jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

here is my code:

```
$("input[name=myText]").replaceWith("<input name='myText' type='text'/>" +
    "Select a number: <select name='numberSelect' id='numberSelect'>" +
    "<option value=''></option>" +
    "<option value='.5'>.5</option>" +
    "<option value='1'>1</option>" +
    "<option value='1.5'>1.5</option>" +
    "<option value='2'>2</option>" +
    "</select>"
    );

$("#numberSelect").change(function () { alert('hello') });
```

I just can't get the event of selecting an item in the dropdown to fire.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using $.live http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$("#numberSelect").live("change", function(){
  alert('hello')
});
```

**UPDATE**

As mentioned below by abraham, as of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. So the new code should be :

```
$("#numberSelect").on("change", function(){
  alert('hello')
});
```

Comment: `live` has been deprecated in jQuery. The new method is `on` which should take the same parameters. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: good point, I totally overlooked that. I've updated my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("input[name=myText]").replaceWith($("<input name='myText' type='text'/>" +
    "Select a number: <select name='numberSelect' id='numberSelect'>" +
    "<option value=''></option>" +
    "<option value='.5'>.5</option>" +
    "<option value='1'>1</option>" +
    "<option value='1.5'>1.5</option>" +
    "<option value='2'>2</option>" +
    "</select>").find('select').change(function () { alert('hello') }).end()
    );
```